# How to Initiate Call from Android Web App

Tags: android, web

I'm developing a web app for android phones and I'm curious if it is possible to initiate call to a user from web interface. So basically, I want to call someone when clicking on their phone number on the web page.

While testing on Samsung GT-I9103, I've noticed that it has this functionality: on a web page, when a user clicks on a number, screen for initiating phone call gets shown. So, there is a way to do what I want. But, this functionality doesn't exist on Sony Ericsson, what makes me believe this really depends on the manufacturer. Am I right?

Also, I've checked phonegap documentation (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/index.html), but can't find what I need.

So, is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is slightly functional through JavaScript, from what I have read.
Refer to:

```
 http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html
```

Section: **Binding JavaScript code to Android code**